# How to make Sass mixin that extends parent?

Tags: css, sass, mixins

You could hard-code extending a selector in Sass like:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: red;
}

.box-green {
    @extend .box;
    color: green;
}
```

And then `.box-green` has all the properties of `.box`, with its own additional ones. What I want to do is write a generic mixin that does that - takes a class, adds all its properties with its own and adds a modifier to the class name. If something like this pseudo-code worked (which it doesn't), it would be ideal.

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: red;

    @include make-modifier(&, green) {
        color: green;
    }
}

@mixin make-modifier(parent, modifier-name) {
   .#{$parent}-#{$modifier-name} {
        @content;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do it? Even if only in the latest version it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simpler solution like this

```
@mixin box($color:"") {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: red;

    @if $color !="" {
      &-#{$color} {
        color: $color;
      }
    }
}

.box {
  @include box(green);
}
```

The output will be:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
}
.box-green {
  color: green;
}
```

An example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/04cb6a6fe14972c3ffe4